# Delete last item from Multidimensional Array and Insert remaining into MySql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Multidimensional Array like this.

```
 [rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => fname1
                [1] => flabel1 
                [2] => numeric 
                [3] => yes,no
                [4] => h1 
                [5] => Y 
                [6] => a1
                [7] => <input id="1" value="remove" type="button">
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => fname2
                [1] => flabel2 
                [2] => text 
                [3] => yes,no
                [4] => h2 
                [5] => Y 
                [6] => a2 
                [7] => <input id="2" value="remove" type="button">
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => fname3
                [1] => flabel3 
                [2] => text 
                [3] => yes,no
                [4] => h3 
                [5] => N 
                [6] => a3  
                [7] => <input id="3" value="remove" type="button">
            )

    )
```

)

I want to remove  in every array. And i am unable to insert these values into MySql
 This is my query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO section_details (fieldname, fieldlabel, fieldtype, fieldoptions, hint, required, actions) VALUES ( ) ";
```

I have tried this

```
$rows = $_REQUEST['rows'];
foreach($rows AS $row)
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

This is giving me the array values. but how to insert into MySql.

Comment: you have no values in your insert query

Comment: values are the array values from multidimensional array, which i am unable to put into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$rows = $_REQUEST['rows'];
    foreach($rows AS $row)
    {
      array_pop($row);//remove last element
        print_r($row);

    //since you have fixed index then your sql will become.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO section_details (fieldname, fieldlabel, fieldtype, fieldoptions, hint, required, actions) VALUES ('$row[0]','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]','$row[6]') ";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unset ($array_name[count($array_name)-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = $_REQUEST['rows'];

foreach($rows AS $row)
{

 unset ($row[count($row)-1]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last element in array in foreach & the implode the array into a string & use the sql

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
   unset($row[count($row)-1]);
   $mysqlStr = implode(',',$row);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO section_details (fieldname, fieldlabel, fieldtype, fieldoptions, hint, required, actions) VALUES ({$mysqlStr}) ";

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO section_details (fieldname, fieldlabel, fieldtype, fieldoptions, hint, required, actions) VALUES ";
$values = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
   unset($row[count($row)-1]);
   $values[] = implode('", "', $row);
}

$sql .= '( "'.implode('", "', $values).'")';
```

This will store the data in a single query.
You shoule use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for validating values.